# Windows 7 and VB6: Event Error ID 1000

Tags: windows-7, crash

I have a completely random error popping up on a particular piece of software out in the field. The application is a game written in VB6 and is running on Windows 7 64-bit. Every once in a while, the app crashes, with a generic "program.exe has stopped responding" message box. This game can run fine for days on end until this message appears, or within a matter of hours. No exception is being thrown.

We run this app in Windows 2000 compatibility mode (this was its original OS), with visual themes disabled, and as an administrator. The app itself is purposely simple in terms of using external components and API calls.

References:

Visual Basic for Applications
Visual Basic runtime objects and procedures
Visual Basic objects and procedures
OLE Automation
Microsoft DAO 3.51 Object Library
Microsoft Data Formatting Object Library

Components:

Microsoft Comm Control 6.0
Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)
Resizer XT

As you can see, these are pretty straightforward, Microsoft-standard tools, for the most part. The database components exist to interact with an Access database used for bookkeeping, and the [Resizer XT](http://www.resizer.com/download.htm) was inserted to move this game more easily from its original 800x600 resolution to 1920x1080.

There is no networking enabled on the kiosks; no network drivers, and hence no connections to remote databases. Everything is encapsulated in a single box.

In the Windows Application event log, when this happens, there is an Event ID 1000 faulting a seemingly random module -- so far, either ntdll.dll or lpk.dll. In terms of API calls, I don't see any from ntdll.dll. We are using kernel32, user32, and winmm, for various file system and sound functions. I can't reproduce as it is completely random, so I don't even know where to start troubleshooting. Any ideas?

EDIT: A little more info. I've tried several different versions of Dependency Walker, at the suggestion of some other developers, and the latest version shows that I am missing IESHIMS.dll and GRPSVC.dll (these two seems to be well-known bugs in Depends.exe), and that I have missing symbols in COMCTRL32.dll and IEFRAME.dll. Any clues there?

Comment: Are you dealing with USB? I have an activeX project which has similar crash (ntdll.dll). After we update the drivers for the thirdparty USB connector (printer), the issue get resolved.

Comment: ¿What does the piece of software do? lpk is a language pack dll and ntdll is somethimes damaged by unexpected shutdowns (or raises errors because of hardware malfunction). So, the range is broad...

Comment: @Esen - we are dealing with a USB-serial adapter using ATEN drivers. However, this is a piece of hardware we use all the time, with the drivers we always use.

Comment: @Alfabravo - the software is a game that basically runs as a standalone kiosk. There are dozens out there and all see this eventually. Any resources for troubleshooting ntdll in general? It seems to be the most common caller by far.

Comment: It would be weird it the dll is damaged in all the kiosks. But can't figure out a common reason.

Comment: Could you please share some more details on what the app does? What technologies it has been using. Which generic activities it has been doing? what are the last logs ? can they be improved. Can you run a "profiler" of some type? 
So many questions...

Comment: Have you tried running the VB6 app in a compatibility mode?

Comment: Any kind of additional detail information about what this application does, special or unusual hardware or third-party libraries, anything that might provide a basis on which to help you diagnose this issue further? Is this app running on a 64-bit version of Windows 7 under the 32-bit subsystem? Is it connecting to any remote databases?

Comment: If you do some searches on the internet;  the broad consensus seems to point to a corrupt DLL / install. For some it was the IDE that was crashing when the application was running with the same error, and a re-install fixed it. Outside of that, the other problem was MSVCRT???.DLL. Similar problem: http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.66179.8

Comment: @Alfabravo I could see it being a corrupt DLL, but how would I know? I had thought that an sfc /scannow would take care of that, but that comes back clean. Being as we dupe all of our drives from a master (bit-by-bit copy), if that drive had a bad DLL, it would certainly propagate the issue to the duped drives.

Comment: @qballer I elaborated in the question to give more detail on what we're doing. The only error that I get now in the event log now is Event ID 1000, faulting ntdll.dll. Would you have a profiler that you could recommend?

Comment: @DavidW We do run in compatibility mode (Windows 2000). I edited the question to reflect that. I also added our references and components. We are running Window 7 64-bit, and no, we don't connect to any remote databases, just a local Access database.

Comment: @DaneBalia I'm going to take a look at some of these potential solutions. Thanks for the link.

Comment: One of the things that I did was check everything with Dependency Walker. It appears that MSVCRT.dll is showing a different File Version and Product Version. Every other dependency checks out. Is this something I should worry about?

Comment: Also, it looks like everything is loading from system32 as opposed to SysWow64. Shouldn't it be loading 32-bit everything for a VB6 app?

Comment: Old post, but still a problem 8 years later. I have a similar situation. IEFRAME.dll seems to be the culprit, but of course you have a major re-write on your hands to live without that. I did just that and it is now stable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message from the application event log isn't that useful - what you need is a post mortem process dump from your process - so you can see where in your code things started going wrong.

Every time I've seen one of these problems it generally comes down to a bad API parameter rather than something more exotic, this may be caused by bad data coming in, but usually it's a good ol fashioned bug that causes the problem.

As you've probably figured already this isn't going to be easy to debug; ideally you'd have a repeatable failure case to debug, instead of relying on capturing dump files from a remote machine, but until you can make it repeatable remote dumps are the only way forwards.

Dr Watson used to do this, but is no longer shipped, so the alternatives are:

- [How to use the Userdump.exe tool to create a dump file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241215)
- [Sysinternals ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx)
- [Collecting User-Mode dumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx)

What you need to get is a minidump, these contain the important parts of the process space, excluding standard modules (e.g. Kernel32.dll) - and replacing the dump with a version number.

There are instructions for [Automatically Capturing a Dump When a Process Crashes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2009/10/15/automatically-capturing-a-dump-when-a-process-crashes.aspx) - which uses cdb.exe shipped with the debugging tools, however the crucial item is the registry key `\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug`

You can change your code to add better error handling - especially useful if you can narrow down the cause to a few procedures and use the techniques described in [Using symbolic debug information to locate a program crash.](http://web.archive.org/web/20040221122322/http://www.fawcette.com/Archives/premier/mgznarch/vbpj/2001/04apr01/bb0401/bb0401.asp) to directly process the map files.

Once you've got a minidump and the symbol files WinDbg is the tool of choice for digging into these dumps - however it can be a bit of a voyage to discover what the cause is.

The only other thing I'd consider, and this depends on your application structure, is to attempt to capture all input events for replay.

Another option is to find a copy of VMWare 7.1 which has [replay debugging](http://www.replaydebugging.com/) and use that as the first step in capturing a reproducible set of steps.

Comment: I am going to get this all set up and maybe head out to one of the remote sites and set it up as a guinea pig. Thanks for all the info. This gives me a lot to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your executable object and let it be WINXP compatible pending
when you discover source of the problem to finally solve it